# How to remove whitespace in String imported from Excel

Tags: java, jxl

I need to remove all white character from a string and I am not able to do so.
Anyone has an idea on how to do it?

Here is my string retrieved from an excel file via jxl API :

```
"Destination à gauche"
```

And here are its bytes :

```
6810111511610511097116105111110-96-32321039711799104101
```

There is the code I use to remove whitespaces :

```
public static void checkEntetes(Workbook book) {
        String sheetName = "mysheet";
        System.out.print(sheetName + " : ");
        for(int i = 0; i < getColumnMax(book.getSheet(sheetName)); i++) {
            String elementTrouve = book.getSheet(sheetName).getCell(i, 0).getContents();
            String fileEntete = new String(elementTrouve.getBytes()).replaceAll("\\s+","");
            System.out.println("\t" + elementTrouve + ", " + bytesArrayToString(elementTrouve.getBytes()));
            System.out.println("\t" + fileEntete + ", " + bytesArrayToString(fileEntete.getBytes()));
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

And this outputs :

```
"Destination à gauche", 6810111511610511097116105111110-96-32321039711799104101
"Destination àgauche", 6810111511610511097116105111110-96-321039711799104101
```

I even tried to make it myself and it still leaves a space before the 'à' char.

```
public static String removeWhiteChars(String s) {
    String retour = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c != (char) ' ') {
            retour += c;
        }
    }
    return retour;
}
```

Comment: Only spaces or all whitespaces? for spaces you could simply do `str.replace(" ", "");`

Comment: I need to remove all whitespaces. This does not work because it does not remove the space before the 'à' char.

Comment: Have you checked the value of that char, maybe it is rendered as whitespace, but not a whitespace character that is selected using `\s`,

Comment: Found [a solution that works](http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/java-remove-white-spaces/) but will be a pain for you to implement. I used that but only for numbers so the legal set of characters was very small.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up ! I'll try to look into it when I have some time !

Answer (score 1):

regular expressions to the rescue:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "")
```

will remove any sequence of whitespace characters. for example:

```
String input = "Destination à gauche";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\s+","");
System.out.println("output is \""+output+"\"");
```

outputs `Destinationàgauche`

if youre starting point is indeed the raw bytes (`byte[]`) you will first need to make them into a String:

```
byte[] inputData = //get from somewhere
String stringBefore = new String(inputData, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); //you need to know the encoding
String withoutSpaces = stringBefore.replaceAll("\\s+","");
byte[] outputData = withoutSpaces.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: I think it comes from the encoding of the string.

Destination??gauche, 6810111511610511097116105111110-17-65-67-17-65-671039711799104101

Is what i get.

Comment: Don't know yet. I'm looking for the answer and once I have it I will replace UTF-8 by this encoding. I'll let you know. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a formula, the TRIM function will do exactly what you're looking for:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+
|    |     A      |           B         |
+----+------------+---------------------+
| 1  | =TRIM(B1)  |  value to trim here |
+----+------------+---------------------+
```

So to do the whole column.
1) Insert a column
2) Insert TRIM function pointed at cell you are trying to correct.
3) Copy formula down the page
4) Copy inserted column
5) Paste as "Values"

Reference: Question number 9578397 on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Using macros is not an option. The excel file is read-only. Thanks for your answer anyway.